# Shopify GraphQL – How to pull abandoned checkouts

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am in the process of converting our project from the Shopify REST API over to the GraphQL API, however, I can't seem to find a way to pull "Abandoned checkouts".

This is the REST API documentation for abandoned checkouts that I am currently using and referencing:
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/abandoned-checkouts

I can't seem to find the equivalent using GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

Schema has nothing on that. Probably a better idea to direct your question at Shopify API dev forums. At least there you're bound to get an answer from Shopify, whereas here, you're bound to hear crickets chirping.